# Statistical Analysis help on Randomized Controlled Trial survey data, using JAMOVI. 4 groups, each with 6 repetitions, large observation size

Tags: mathematical-statistics, randomized-tests

I made this RCT survey to test whether any change of information presented/attached to a secondhand product might change the customer’s willingness to pay on higher price level.

Control group (limited information): n=253

Treatment 1 (adding information on extrinsic value of the produce): n=286

Treatment 2 (adding information on intrinsic value of the produce): n=261

Treatment 3 (mixture of treatment 1 and 2): n=257

participants were assigned to each group randomly
each participant only answer the survey once
each participant were given 6 questions, that asked the same thing about 6 different items
each question had 9 answer choice in ordinal manner (I have labeled the answers into score 1-9, being 9 as the highest score)

Hypothesis that I want to test:

1. Treatment 1 has significantly higher score than Control
2. Treatment 2 has significantly lower score than Control
3. Treatment 3 has significantly higher score than Control, but not as high as Treatment 1
4. There is negative correlation between Treatment 1 and 2

Main aims of analysis:

1. Find out correlation between each group
2. Find out if there is any significant difference between each group

Other than those 2 main aims above, please kindly share if you have any other suggestion of analysis that might be interesting to look at.

Thank you in advance.